# localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to convert this app to docker but I'm getting this error.

Here's my express.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const portNumber = 3000;
const sourceDir = "dist";
const expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
app.use(
  "/",
  expressStaticGzip(sourceDir, {
    enableBrotli: true,
    orderPreference: ["br", "gz"],
    setHeaders: function(res, path) {
      res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=31536000");
    }
  })
);

app.listen(portNumber, () => {
  console.log(`Express web server started: http://localhost:${portNumber}`);
  console.log(`Serving content from /${sourceDir}/`);
});
```

here's my dockerfile

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "node", "express.js" ]
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

This is a very common error. When you're broadcasting within a docker container you usually have to listen on host `0.0.0.0` not just `localhost`. If you listen on `localhost` docker won't be able to route traffic from outside of the container to the loopback interface within the container.

You can fix this by updating your express code to listen on `0.0.0.0`. I believe that's this:

```js
app.listen(portNumber, "0.0.0.0", () => {
  console.log(`Express web server started: http://0.0.0.0:${portNumber}`);
  console.log(`Serving content from /${sourceDir}/`);
});
```

You'll then need to run the dockerfile with something like:

```
docker build -t node-app .
docker run -p 3000:3000 node-app
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I tried this but still the same issue

Comment: docker run --name node-appp -d -p 8080:8080 node-app

Comment: try `docker run --name node-appp -d -p 3000:3000 node-app`

Comment: updated my answer to include that as well. since you used `-d` you might also need to stop it first with `docker kill node-app` `docker rm node-app`

Comment: I did and now I'm getting this error "Cannot GET /"

Comment: how are you making the request?

Comment: docker build -t node-app . then docker run --name node-appp -d -p 3000:3000 node-app and then http://localhost:3000/

Comment: i have also updated my file like you've told.

Comment: what's the output of `docker ps` ?

Comment: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
60a1766ad6bd        node-app            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   node-appp

Answer (score 7):

I was running the angular application using the command `ng serve` and facing the same problem.

Because the live development server listens to `http://localhost:4200` by default.

than I used the command `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` to run the angular project and that solved my problem.

Comment: THANK YOU! I was wondering why I couldn't get ng serve to work with docker compose

Comment: You are my hero! :)

Comment: You saved my day! This also works with Nx + dockerized React app. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was using such command and getting your error

```
docker run -p 32546:80 myimage
```

Or

```
docker run -p 32555:443 myimage
```

After a couple of tries, I figured out that it was not working on the browser cause of ports 80 & 443 so I decided to use another port like '8080' or '4200'

Therefore, I changed my command like the below

```
docker run -p 32665:4200
```

Comment: this worked for me somehow port 80 was giving me errors tried with 4300 and now it works